# Searching for a non-constant regular expression

Tags: tcl

I want to find a pattern in a file, but the pattern can have several forms. 
Here is the code :

```
while {[gets $thefile line] >= 0} {
     for {set nb_table 1} {$nb_table<$count_table} {incr nb_table} {
          if { [regexp {pattern_$nb_table} $line] } {
          puts "I found one !"
          }
     }
}
```

the var `$count_table` is known, catched before on a on a other procedure.

If i do a puts of `pattern_$nb_table` in the for loop i got the name of all tables and that's good, but I never have `I found one!` printed out (sure i want to be another process but it is not the subject). Why I never go in the `if`? My file contains the pattern : `pattern_1 pattern_2 .....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the variable is not being substituted into the regular expression (the `{`…`}` disable all immediate substitutions). This is a situation where you'd use (putting the variable name in braces just for clarity, and putting the pattern in double quotes for highlighting *only*):

```
if {[regexp "pattern_${nb_table}" $line]} { ... }
```

Except that if I was looking for a string that simple, I'd try to use `string first` or `string match`:

```
if {[string first "pattern_${nb_table}" $line] >= 0} { ... }
```

```
if {[string match "*pattern_${nb_table}*" $line]} { ... }
```

Both of these are faster than regular expression matching, provided you're doing something simple. If the rest of the *real* `pattern` is a regular expression, only `regexp` will do. Of course.